# How to disable shift key paste function in Android studio editor?

Tags: android-studio

Pressing shift key in editor, pastes previous lines multiple times. I tried it on 2 keyboards but problem persist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Settings -> Keymap -> Search by "paste"
It will display all possible Paste actions and mapped keys. Check all look good or fix accordingly

Comment: Insert key of laptop might have shorted

Comment: Removed all paste except ctrl+v

Answer (score 0):

Many keys of the laptop might have shorted, problem is solved after disabling laptop keyboard and using new wireless keyboard